# How to join a many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Entities :

- Model
- Category
- Keyword

Model has a many to many relationship to keyword as well as category has a many to many relationship to keyword.

The orm generates following tables

- model
- category
- keyword
- keyword_model
- keyword_category

When a category is given, how can I get all models related to this category? I would do it like this

- get all keyword id's from keyword_category by category.id
- join the result with the keyword_model table
- the result of the join should be all relevant model id's

Since symfony2 deals with entities and not tables it seems hard to create a mysql query. I tried with something like

```
SELECT x,y FROM MyBundle:Category x, MyBundle:Model y
        JOIN x.keywords
        JOIN y.keywords
            WHERE
                x.id = " . $category . "
```

however this is invalid mysql syntax. Any ideas how to get the models here?

Comment: You want to use sql(dql)?

Comment: @DonCallisto would be good, however any solution is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
SELECT 
   y 
FROM 
    MyBundle:Model y
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            x
        FROM
            MyBundle:Category x
        JOIN
            x.keywords xk
        WHERE
            xk MEMBER OF y.keywords AND
            x = :category
    )
```

Or if your relations are [bidirectional](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional):

```
SELECT 
   y 
FROM 
    MyBundle:Model y
JOIN
    y.keywords yk
JOIN
    yk.categories c
WHERE
    c = :category
```

Answer (score 1):

From a given category (I suppose that you have the id)

```
$category_repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('YourBundleName:Category');
$category = $category_repo->findOneById($id); //$id is your entity id
$keywords = $category->getKeywords(); //getKeywords() is the name of the method that you should have inside your class
$models = new ArrayCollection(); //or use a simple array
foreach($keywords as $keyword) {
  foreach($keyword->getModels() as $model) {
    $models->add($model);
  }
}
```

however use sql directly should be more performing as you'll do a single query instead of a query (lazy-loading concept) for each object

Comment: hm there is no relation between category and model, there is a relation between category and keyword, and model and keyword